# CSS not able to retrieve property of an element

Tags: jquery, css

I am using CSS as below, when i try to get value of border color it returns null/blank value?

css

```
INPUT {
    FONT: 100% verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    COLOR: #000000;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFECEC;
    BORDER-COLOR:#993333;
    BORDER-STYLE:solid;
    BORDER-WIDTH:1px;
}

$(window).load(function() {
  alert( $('#Bclose').css('background-color'));
});
```

Comment: Please share you html code.

Comment: Works just fine for me with a `$(document).ready()` callback: http://jsfiddle.net/JdkTP/

Comment: Right, and what happened when you traced the code with the debugger?

Comment: Please **stop** writing UPPERCASE properties, and selectors! It's bugging me. :(

Answer (score 0):

you could apply a class name to your input as an alternative method...

css

```
.inputStyle{background-color:#afa;}
```

html

```
<input class="inputStyle" type="text" value="hello" />
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

alert($('.inputStyle').css('background-color'));

});
```

check it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/RkWLG/

using just the input selector also works, http://jsfiddle.net/RkWLG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
input {
    font: 100% verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    background-color:#FFECEC;
    border-color:#993333;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    var bgcolor = $('#Bclose').css('background-color');
alert(bgcolor);
});

<input type="text" id="Bclose">
    <a id="clickme">click</a>
```

This will return the color when you click text. Can also be set without click function. Just use

```
var bgcolor = $('#Bclose').css('background-color'); alert(bgcolor);
```

Here is a **[live working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rqpGF/)**

*Note: Always try to use with document.ready.function*